# Jammy - resolvectl domain persistent across reboots

Tags: networking, server, dns, 22.04

Much that I have searched AU for similar questions, I came up null for 22.04 - although maybe this is nothing to do with 22.04

I am looking to know how to make a search domain persistent across reboots.

I use the following command to set the local cloud domain

```
resolvectl domain eth0 organisational.cloud
```

It works great - until I reboot the machine..

How is one meant to add a persistent search domain?

I see something in man about /etc/systemd/network but I'm not sure that is for legacy support or not.  The resolv.conf file (and others) all say Do not edit.

Comment: It depends on your system. Generally I edit the `Domains=` entry in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and then doing `sudo  systemctl restart systemd-resolved`

Answer (score 1):

In my Fedora 36 system, which is a fixed IPv4 address, I was also looking for how to persist the local domain DNS settings without doing *sudo resolvectl domain enp5s0 haapi.org* all the time. FedKad's comment has turned out to be spot-on.

I edited the [Resolve] section of /etc/systemd/resolved.conf:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=192.168.77.88  # my local LAN's DNS server
Domains=haapi.org  # my local domain
```

Then, *systemctl restart systemd-resolved*
as FedKad said, and it worked. Even better, it worked after a reboot, so now I can ssh to my myriad RPi4s by short name after reboots and suspends.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. Netplan was configured to get its config from NetworkManager (Look at `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`). I ended up using `nmcli` like this :

```
$ sudo nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 1" ipv4.dns "10.24.1.119,8.8.8.8"
```

You can get the connection name using `nmcli connection` and check your modifications with `nmcli connection show "Wired connection 1"`.

*PS* : Those modifications will be displayed on GUI Network settings.

Source : [pimylifeup.com](https://pimylifeup.com/ubuntu-set-dns-servers/#changing-ubuntu-s-dns-settings-using-the-network-manager)

Comment: David, thanks - I don't really understand your answer (I didn't mark it down) - but the @FedKad comment worked for me a charm..